# Unable to create a proper method for a quadrant checker program

Tags: java

I'm not sure how to exactly use the the public static method with if/else statements that only return a character. The program is supposed to take x,y and return what quadrant the coordinates are located within. (A noob to java!)

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Assignment13 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userInputx,
            userInputy;
        double x, y, answer;

        userInputx = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your x coordinate.");
        x = Double.parseDouble(userInputx);

        userInputy = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your y coordinate.");
        y = Double.parseDouble(userInputy);

        answer = MethodQuad.quadrant(x, y);

        System.out.println("The coordinates " + x + y + "are located Quadrant " + answer);
    }
}

class MethodQuad {

    public static double quadrant(double x, double y) {

        if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
            return System.out.println("1");
        } else if (x < 0 && y > 0) {
            return System.out.println("2");
        } else if (x < 0 && y < 0) {
            return System.out.println("3");
        } else if (x < 0 && y > 0) {
            return System.out.println("4");
        } else {
            return System.out.println("0");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: I think a quadrant function that can return one of *five* values for valid coordinates is a bit... unnecessarily complicated and mathematically arbitrary. Unless you were told to do it that way, I'd suggest using >= 0 and < 0, then the axes and origin also count as being in quadrants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It work like in another programming language. If you wrote return value, you must return some value)

```
 class MethodQuad {
 public static int quadrant(double x, double y)
 {

   if(x > 0 && y > 0)
     return 1;
   else if(x < 0 && y > 0)
     return 2;
   else if(x < 0 && y < 0)
     return 3;
   else if (x<0 && y >0) 
     return 4; 
   else 
     return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're telling the method that it will return a double in its signature line:

```
public static double quadrant(double x, double y)
```

The compiler won't like this since the method is not in fact returning a double (nor should it). I suggest you change that line so that it knows it will return a **String** instead. You probably know how to do this, right?

Also, in your class, you're declaring answer to be a double variable which doesn't make logical sense:

```
double x, 
       y,
  answer;
```

What variable type should `answer` be declared as?

**Edit**
You'll also want to post your assignment instructions so we can see exactly what you're supposed to be doing. You could potentially make answer an int and have the method return an int -- if that's what the teacher wanted. So let's see what they told you to do.